# How can I remove fields in the attachment editor?

Tags: custom-field, attachments, editor

Is it possible to remove a default attachment field from the attachment editor, for example the "Caption" field ?

To give you some context, I'm trying to build a custom attachment editor page. I found how to [add custom fields](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-custom-fields-for-attachments-in-wordpress/), now I'd like to remove some of the default ones I don't need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to hide buttons from Attachment window](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5645/trying-to-hide-buttons-from-attachment-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attachment_fields_to_edit filter to remove the fields you don't want displaying from the array.

```
function remove_caption($fields) {
  unset($fields['post_excerpt']); // See wp-admin\includes\media.php line 1071
  return $fields;
}
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit','remove_caption');
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in WP 3.5+