# Customize the upload screen

Tags: admin, user-roles, uploads

I would need to simplify the "upload new image" interface for our Authors : basically, hide a few fields that will only confuse my wordpress "authors" (like the "Description" and "Alt" text inputs). Administrators and Editors need to see these, though.

How can i implement that hiding/showing inputs according to the user's priviledges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to hook into `attachment_fields_to_edit` and unset them for a role.

You can use `current_user_can('author')`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Example to remove image alt field

```
function remove_caption($form_fields) {

  if (current_user_can('author')){
   $form_fields['image_alt']['input'] = 'hidden';
   return $form_fields;
}}
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit','remove_caption', 15, 2);
```

My initial post used `unset` but I tried it and it did not work, from the example in this post: [How can I remove fields in the attachment editor?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14817/how-can-i-remove-fields-in-the-attachment-editor) , not sure why, instead the example above works using `hidden`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot!  For the record, i've published a broader function with more options so that others don't have to look °-) http://pixeline.be/blog/development/customize-the-wordpress-upload-interface-805.html