# How can I remove the image attachment ALT field?

Tags: images, filters, attachment-fields-to-edit

I've been using the technique described in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14817/how-can-i-remove-fields-in-the-attachment-editor) to remove the caption and description fields in the uploads modal window, thus eliminating unused clutter for users. Since the title field is already required when uploading images in WordPress, it's easiest for my users to dispense with the alt field altogether and just pull the alt text from the title field when displaying images on a website.

From what I'm seeing in the media.php file, I should be able to unset the alt field by adding this to my function: `unset($form_fields['image_alt']);`, but it's not working. Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This would be very bad for your site: the `alt` attribute is reserved for a functional equivalent of the image. It _cannot_ be the same as the `title`. Just imagine you were forced to use a screen reader and had to listen to each `title` twice.

Comment: Have you read the article linked at? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5645/5424. Using the pre 3.5 uploader this _should_ work.

Comment: @toscho My problem is that most users leave the alt field empty, which is a bigger issue for SEO and accessibility. Using this approach I can at least ensure there will be some alt text, and either disable the title field completely in the output or auto-populate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you will come up with a solution to the accessibility issue pointed by @toscho...

Putting a [lower priority](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) (later execution) to the filter does the job.

> **$priority** *(integer) (optional)*
>   Used to specify the order in which the
>   functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower
>   numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same
>   priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
>   action.
>   Default: 10

```
function remove_caption( $fields ) {
    unset( $fields['image_alt'] );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'remove_caption', 999, 1 );
```

Comment: 999 is an exaggeration... 11 is enough, 15 just to be sure :)

Comment: Perfect! Didn't realize I could change the priority, though it looked like that was causing the issue. Works great now.

Comment: Is this still relevant? I am running 3.9.1 and this code does not work for me.

Comment: Looks like they killed this filter in 3.6 without really telling anyone.
It is still there, but as far as I can tell it can now only be used to add fields, not to unset.
I spent a good while looking for a way to do it, but ended up using simple CSS hiding (oh, the shame!).

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy, your [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/134263) was ok but why did you put that weird edit summary??