# How to hide / remove attachment "alt" or "caption" field in Admin?

Tags: hooks, attachments, captions

Until WP 3.6 it was possible to remove the "alt" field (and also the "caption" field) before showing a post of type "attachment" through **attachment_fields_to_edit hook**.

As you can see also [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72903/how-can-i-remove-the-image-attachment-alt-field) (user Olemak's comment to the solution) WP removed the possibility to...remove fields from that hook from 3.6 version on.

Do you know other methods to get this result in WP, or I have to resort to a Css-only solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `attachment_fields_to_edit`function returns an array variable called: `$form_fields`, which contains all the data. So as it is an array, we could make any of these operations in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array).

There are some methods to delete an array element, including `unset()` method, which I think it's the easy method to use.

And to delete the **caption field**, I'm not so sure but I think you should unset this: `$form_fields['post_excerpt']`, this contains the caption content. Take a look at the code function in this code [link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1217).

Comment: no, $form_fields is given as an empty array in "attachment_fields_to_edit" hook, as from WP 3.6 onwards....

Comment: Hey! You're right, I haven't noticed! Seems to work only to add new fields, sorry. Maybe using JS or CSS, could be the best option.